# DynamoDB InvalidParameterType Error While Trying To Put A New Item

Tags: javascript, php, database, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to implement a DynamoDB based application to store some request data. I read the DynamoDB official documentation and currently I am following [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/sweet-treats-for-dynamodb-users/) official tutorial to do some basic operations.

I am using a local DynamoDB docker container. You can run it with this:

`docker run -d -p 8000:8000 amazon/dynamodb-local:latest -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb`

When I try to create a new table just same as the tutorial I gave above, I got no error, everything is fine:

```
var params = {
TableName: 'book',
KeySchema: [
    {
        AttributeName: 'title',
        KeyType: 'HASH',
    }
],
AttributeDefinitions: [
    {
        AttributeName: 'title',
        AttributeType: 'S'
    }
],
ProvisionedThroughput: {
    ReadCapacityUnits: 1, 
    WriteCapacityUnits: 1, 
}

};
dynamodb.createTable(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) print(err); // an error occurred
    else print(data); // successful response

});
```

But when I try to put some new items in it:

```
var params = {
TableName: 'book',
Item: { // a map of attribute name to AttributeValue
    title: "Sample Application: CloudList",
    chapter: 10
    }
};

dynamodb.putItem(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) print(err); // an error occurred
    else print(data); // successful response
});
```

I got this error:

[image]

31 validation error actually is equal to number of chars in title: `Sample Application: CloudList`. DynamoDB shell also did not recognized the print function which is given in the above tutorial. So I had to replace it with ppJson function. Where am I doing wrong and how can I put/delete/get items from DynamoDB via Web Shell? (and also via PHP code)

---

Edit: I also tried what Vikdor said in the comment, it seems I got rid of that `UnexpectedParameter` error but this time I got `Invalid attribute value type` error.

```
var params = {
    TableName: 'book',
    Item: { // a map of attribute name to AttributeValue
        'title': {S: "Sample Application: CloudList"},
        'chapter': {N: '10'}
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/dynamodb-example-table-read-write.html) explains the structure of the `Item` key in the `params` passed to the API and your `params` should be as follows:

```
var params = {
    TableName: "book",
    Item: { 
        "title": {"S": "Sample Application: CloudList"},
        "chapter": {"N": :10"}
    }
};
```

Note that even the numbers should be enclosed in quotes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Now I am getting `Invalid attribute value type` error. But it seems everything correct according to that doc. I could not find what's wrong here.

Comment: Could you please add an edit to your answer with the corrected `params` value to see what else is wrong with the param construction? @JollyRoger

Comment: I used the exact params value in your answer. Should I still add it to the question?

Comment: oh! okay. It just makes your question complete, that's all! @JollyRoger

Comment: I updated the params value to use all double quotes, even for the types and verified that it worked using AWS command line JSON. @JollyRoger